# How to deal with Spring hibernate no lock aquired exception inside a transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have applied @Transactional in my interface, and inside my serviceImpl, the corresponding method is calling some other methods, one method is reading, another method is writing. Although I have anotated as Transactional, when I am giving concurrent request, my insert method is throwing `org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException:` error.
Another problem is, this insert method is a shared method and it performs the insert method like Dao.save(obj) . Dao.save() is a generic method So i can not do anything here. I have to apply something on interface to avoid no lock aquired exception. 
Is it possible to tell wait untill lock is aquired? Or retry if transaction is failed? Or lock all the tables until the transaction is completed so that another request can not access the relevent resources?
My hibernate version is 3.x, And database is mysql 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is,

1. Mark your methods transactional
2. In your mysql database settings set the transaction isolation level as **SERIALIZABLE**